# Does declaring a field as final force redundancy in the constructors?

Tags: java, dry

I have the following abbreviated class:

```
public class Player {
    final private DoubleDuple position;
    final private DoubleDuple momentum;

    public Player() {
        position = new DoubleDuple(0, 0);
        momentum = new DoubleDuple(0, 0);
    }

    public Player(double xPos, double yPos) {
        position = new DoubleDuple(xPos, yPos);
        momentum = new DoubleDuple(0, 0);
    }

    public Player(double xPos, double yPos, double xMom, double yMom) {
        position = new DoubleDuple(xPos, yPos);
        momentum = new DoubleDuple(xMom, yMom);
    }
}
```

With the fields being listed as `final`, I can't just have each more complicated constructor call each simpler constructor, since the `final` field would then be assigned twice; which isn't allowed.

If though, I removed the `final` modifier from the fields, I could change the last constructor to:

```
public Player(double xPos, double yPos, double xMom, double yMom) {
        this(xPos, yPos);
        momentum = new DoubleDuple(xMom, yMom);
}
```

Which I find neater. In this example, it's not much of a change, but in situations where there are more fields that have defaultable values, it would be nice to not have to repeat myself in each constructor (DRY).

Questions:

- When dealing with `final` fields, is there any way to not repeat myself in each constructor?
- I'm asking this to abide by the DRY (Don't repeat yourself) principal. Should I be thinking this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way I usually do it is to code only the last constructor, and then make the simpler constructors delegate to the most complete one, by providing default values.
So, taking your example, I'd so it like this:

```
public class Player {
    final private DoubleDuple position;
    final private DoubleDuple momentum;

    public Player() {
        this(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public Player(double xPos, double yPos) {
        this(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);
    }

    public Player(double xPos, double yPos, double xMom, double yMom) {
        position = new DoubleDuple(xPos, yPos);
        momentum = new DoubleDuple(xMom, yMom);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ahh! I'm embarrassed I didn't think of that. Thank you.